# Как можно оптимизировать следующий код?

Tags: java, оптимизация

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /*если окно уже создано и не закрыто, то выводим на передний план*/
        if((nf != null) && !nf.isClosed()){

            theDesctop.add(nf, 0);
            try {
                nf.setSelected(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1)
                {e1.printStackTrace();}
        }else{
            xLocation += 26;
            yLocation += 26;
            if(xLocation > 78 && yLocation > 78){
                xLocation = 26;
                yLocation = 26;
            }

            //nf = new NodeFrame("СМС: Узлы", 20, 30, 405, 500);
            nf = new NodeFrame("СМС: Узлы", xLocation, yLocation, 405, 500);
            theDesktop.add(nf, 0);
            nf.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Собственно таких участков очень большое количество, меняется только конструктор фреймов. Можно ли как то выделить этот код в метод?
**UPD1:** Ещё пример

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*Если окно уже создано и не закрыто, то выводим на передний план*/
                if((ptf != null) && !ptf.isClosed()){

                    theDesctop.add(ptf, 0);
                    try {
                        ptf.setSelected(true);
                    } catch (PropertyVetoException e1)
                        {e1.printStackTrace();}
                }else{
                    xLocation += 26;
                    yLocation += 26;
                    if(xLocation > 78 && yLocation > 78){
                        xLocation = 26;
                        yLocation = 26;
                    }

                    //ptf = new ProductTypeFrame("СМС: Тип изделия", 20, 30, 220, 240);
                    ptf = new ProductTypeFrame("СМС: Тип изделия", xLocation, yLocation, 220, 240);
                    theDesktop.add(ptf, 0);
                    ptf.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: Вынести нужные значения в параметры и обозвать метод :)

Comment: Эм, конструктор для каждого фрейма свой.

Comment: @AlexChermenin как я конструктор помещу в параметры, а потом вызову?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе альтернативный пример? Будет понятнее как это отрефакторить .

Comment: @Nofate Привел - upd1

Comment: 1. Т.е. меняются только сам конструктор `*Frame`и его первый и два последних параметра, количество параметров постоянно?   2. `ProductTypeFrame` и `NodeFrame` имеют общего родителя?

Comment: @Nofate прошу прощения. Перерубили интернет(физически) - не мог ответить)

Comment: @Nofate 1. Да. 2. Да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Исхожу из предположения, что `ProductTypeFrame` и `NodeFrame` имеют общего родителя или интерфейс, назовем его `Frame`.*

Ваш код по сути выполняет показ `Frame`, лежащего в некотором поле. Если поле неинициализировано или `Frame` уже был закрыт, вы создаете новое. По сути вы хотите вынести из этого кода создание экземпляра и присвоение его полю. В конструктор при этом должны попасть параметры `xLocation` и `yLocation`. Для инкапсуляции создания экземпляра класса подходит шаблон проектирования [Абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Мы применим упрощенную реализацию на лямбдах.

Обернем ваш код в метод, который будет принимать параметром лямбду, служащую оберткой для конструктора, и вызывать ее, когда потребуется создать объект. Метод также будет возвращать старый или вновь созданный экземпляр `Frame`, чтобы мы могли присвоить его в переменную/поле.

```
public Frame forceShow(Frame frame, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Frame> frameSupplier) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /*если окно уже создано и не закрыто, то выводим на передний план*/
            if((frame != null) && !frame.isClosed()){
                theDesktop.add(frame, 0);
                try {
                    frame.setSelected(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                xLocation += 26;
                yLocation += 26;
                if(xLocation > 78 && yLocation > 78){
                    xLocation = 26;
                    yLocation = 26;
                }

                frame = frameSupplier.apply(xLocation, yLocation);
                theDesktop.add(frame, 0);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            return frame;
        }
    });  
}
```

Теперь мы можем показать разные виды `Frame`:

```
nf = forceShow(nf, (x, y) -> new NodeFrame("СМС: Узлы", x, y, 405, 500));
ptf = forceShow(ptf, (x, y) -> new ProductTypeFrame("СМС: Тип изделия", x, y, 220, 240));
```

Конструктор будет вызван, только когда метод `forceShow` вызовет `frameSupplier.apply()`

Comment: Немного не понятно, но спасибо! Буду разбираться!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if((nf != null) && !nf.isClosed()){

        theDesctop.add(nf, 0);
        try {
            nf.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e1)
            {e1.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

можно выделить в отдельный метод и передавать nf или ptf. Из метода возвращать boolean значение и на основе него делать блок else дальше

---

```
xLocation += 26;
yLocation += 26;
if(xLocation > 78 && yLocation > 78){
   xLocation = 26;
   yLocation = 26;
}
```

это точно можно в отдельный метод выкинуть.

---

Либо можно заморочиться с рефлексией и выделить все в отдельный метод, в него передавать объект nf/ptf + Class который надо создать. В методе использовать не прямой конструктор f Class.newInstance.